# Installing LyX 2.3.0 on Ubuntu 18.04, Bionic - Repository does not have a release file?

Tags: lyx, ubuntu

I tried installing LyX 2.3.0 following the instructions I found [here](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu), but I got the error  message that 'The repository does not have a release file' so apt-get won't let me add it.

My other laptop is running Ubuntu 16.04 and I didn't have this problem, and it's quite annoying since I have a bunch of LyX documents written on the 2.3.0 version which can't be opened by the latest addition available in Ubuntu's repository.

Comment: This seems to be a general problem that I get when trying to add repositories - I tried to add the KXStudio repository for instance and no joy.

Comment: Exactly, the problem is incompatible file structures on LyX 18.4.
Would posit a guess, that an update is coming for LyX 18.4 to 2.3.0-1, but would be really nice to just know when.

Answer (score 7):

Tried on July 2018, with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, and it worked without issues. I just did as per the doc:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyx-devel/release`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install lyx`

Comment: That's great it's working now. Just for reference, I think the core problem was tracked and solved with this ticket: https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11166

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me is to install the version 2.3 from a previous release (I used 17.10).

If you go to the official PPA (https://launchpad.net/~lyx-devel/+archive/ubuntu/release) you will find it.  Click on "view package details" and download the packages from the release of your choice. In my case, `lyx-common_2.3.0-1~artful~ppa1_all.deb` and `lyx_2.3.0-1~artful~ppa1_amd64.deb`. I am assuming you have a 64-bit installation.

Remove your current lyx installation using `sudo apt purge lyx && sudo apt autoremove`. I recommend installing `apt-get install texlive-generic-extra` before proceeding since this package is removed when you uninstall the "old" lyx.

To proceed installing the packages you just donwloaded. `sudo dpkg -i lyx-common_2.3.0-1~artful~ppa1_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i lyx_2.3.0-1~artful~ppa1_amd64.deb`. It should work fine.

PS: If it complains about dependencies, do a `sudo apt install -f`.

Comment: Cheers! My solution was to install Ubuntu 16.04 since I had problems installing a bunch of other programs.